# Denied Entry into USA - Impact on Future Travel

Tags: visas, usa, borders, canadian-citizens, denial-of-entry

My colleague and I were denied into the USA today from Canada for a work-sanctioned trip. We are both Canadian citizens with Canadian passports. My colleague was unable to properly communicate the objectives of our travel and unfortunately the border guards interpreted this as work that would require to have TN visas. So they took fingerprints and whatnot and denied us access. A few questions:

1. What will be the impact of this when traveling to USA for pleasure? Are there any restrictions I should be aware of in the future?
2. Is there a certain duration in which the information will be removed from the file?
3. Will I require a Visa whenever I travel to the USA for work related reasons? Meetings for example.
4. Will this impact the potential for immigration in the future? Note: not interested in immigrating, just curious.

Comment: Will this impact future travel? Absolutely no doubt.

Comment: Contact a good immigration lawyer in the US (specifically, someone who regularly deals with corporate travel) right away. Because in some countries (not sure about the US), you can appeal decisions made at the border, but you have a short time window in which to do it.

Comment: Get a new colleague, and a new workplace. When I worked for a multinational at their overseas HQ, there was *literally* a script and practices for non-US citizens to use at the USA border. (As a USA national, I skipped the lesson.)

Comment: I'm actually pretty upset with my employer. We have had no training when it comes to crossing the border, and we do it all the time. We are expected to 'massage' the truth to avoid paperwork and cost. And being a huge multinational corporation, you'd think they'd have better processes in place. Of course I have to blame myself as well, I should have done some background reading to better prepare. Lesson learned.

Comment: @radian You would not believe the amount of time and effort companies have to waste getting *just the right letter* and *exactly the right answer for their employees*. It's really unfortunate :( Even with lawyers drafting letters, you can still run into issues.

Comment: @EugeneO There is no reason to appeal not being let in. If they say you need a TN-1, then you have to apply for a TN-1 or cross your fingers that the next border agent you talk to is more agreeable and you learn to answer the questions properly.

Comment: @radian That sucks they expected you to 'massage' the truth. Any chance of just driving across? Much easier to say you're going on vacation then...

Comment: @Jedidja - Either the border agents were right, and a TN was needed in this case, or they were wrong and a TN was not actually needed (e.g. employees of Canadian companies doing work such as training or installation on-site for US clients generally don't need a TN). In this latter case, it makes sense to appeal (if an appeal is permitted, I'm not sure if it is), at least to remove the negative record from one's immigration record.

Comment: @EugeneO I have never come across evidence that this was possible; if you could find a link I'd be very interested in reading it. My experience with US Border Agents is even if you're in the "right", you're not going to gain anything by trying to prove it :)

Comment: My only experience appealing a border officer decision is with a UK border agent - they have a formal appeals process. I don't know if one exists in the USA, so I don't have a link or anything.

Comment: Actually, here it is: https://trip.dhs.gov/ and http://www.dhs.gov/dhs-trip - it's somewhat confusing because they've lumped immigration concerns together with airline security concerns. I don't know if that's the only appeals/complaints program available.

Comment: And then there's this, in case of serious misconduct by border agents: http://www.uscis.gov/about-us/report-uscis-misconduct/report-uscis-employee-misconduct

Comment: @EugeneO Ok, so it is a possibility. My experience (and others') would be that appealing in this particular instance (because it's very, very common) wouldn't lead to your problem being solved any more quickly than either getting the proper documentation or learning how to answer the questions "properly".

Comment: I don't disagree that having proper docs and learning to answer properly are important. The point of appealing would be to remove a negative entry from your record. Otherwise, the next time you appear at a border, you're already marked as a "person who has been denied entry in the past", which automatically puts you under suspicion - and even if you have the proper docs and answer the questions properly next time, you could still face problems.

Answer (score 4):

I've been in exactly this situation.

1. There are no official restrictions (see below), but you may get asked extra questions. As long as you weren't denied entry because you were in the US too long (and it sounds like you weren't), this is not a "bad" denial as if you were a criminal and denied entry.
2. I couldn't find any information on this, but I have had friends who were denied TN-1 entry (or forgot to return their TN-1 card on exiting) that still get questioned about it 10 years later.
3. No, not required, but each border agent is different. Officially, if you are going for a short period of time for business, no one cares: provided you are explicit it is for meetings, no work will be performed there, etc. But again, the "official" rules are subject to the whim of the border agent. The key is to prove that *no work* will be performed, otherwise it falls under the requirements for a TN-1.

   > The nonimmigrant NAFTA Professional (TN) visa allows citizens of Canada and Mexico, as NAFTA professionals, to work in the United States in prearranged business activities for U.S. or foreign employers (http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/employment/nafta.html)
4. It should not, as it is not a "real" denial of entry in any sort of criminal-related manner. The border agents in Ottawa were quite clear about this.

http://www.tnvisabulletin.com/nafta-tn-blog/2010/5/4/entry-as-a-visitor-allowed-after-tn-visa-denial.html

The most relevant sections are here:

> For example, if the inspector denied the TN application due to an accumulation of unlawful presence under INA § 212 (a) (9), this could result in a 3/10 year bar to the U.S. Egregious immigration violators may be expedited removed from the U.S., which results in a 5 year bar to the U.S. If the border inspector denied the application based on fraud under INA § 212 (a) (6), this would result in a lifetime bar to the U.S. In most of these scenarios, only subsequent obtainment of a waiver may permit entry to the U.S.

(That doesn't seem to apply to you.)

> If the inspector denies the TN visa application because he/she believes that the applicant does not meet the basic requirements for the TN, the denial (generally issued under INA § 212 (a) (7) (A) (i) (I)) normally does not result in a specific bar to the U.S. However, the denial usually will result in heightened scrutiny the next time the individual seeks admission to the U.S.

(This does seem relevant)

Comment: this is the key. Meetings don't require a TN1. Working does. For a TN1 you need a letter explaining the work you're doing, and you need your university transcipts (not just your degree.) ON PAPER. If they are sending you to work, get your TN1 stuff together for the next trip. It is generally not held against you if you're turned away for not having X and come back later to apply for X properly. It is held against you if you keep going there to work but claiming it's meetings, or if you were denied an X and try to get in without it.

Comment: @KateGregory Agreed (meetings don't require a TN1); convincing them that you're only going for meetings (especially if your trip is >1 week) can be very difficult.

Comment: That's because it's highly unlikely that it's only meetings if it's more than a week. That's never been the case for me, for example, unless I'm tacking some sightseeing onto a three-days-of-meetings trip.

Answer (score -9):

1. almost certainly. You're now on all kinds of lists of people who need to be scrutinised.
2. probably, there's usually an expiration clause on such things as there is on anything (even life sentences to prison in many countries last only for 20-25 years).
3. possibly, though more likely you won't be able to travel to the US at all for some time and after that things will return to normal
4. quite likely. It's a black mark on your record that will stay, for considerable time

   You'd best contact a US consulate or embassy and ask to speak to someone with knowledge about immigration issues, they're the ones who should be able to tell or find out.
   And they'll most likely tell you to stay out of the US for x years or things go badly for you.

Comment: -1 "probably", "possibly", "quite likely". It is all speculation. The only valid point is to contact the consulate, but that is more a comment then an answer.

Comment: Staying out of the US is not an option, unless I want to find a new job, which I'm not going to do. It just need means I'll need to have all the proper documentation in order before crossing. No more honor system for me. I do wish the US would be a bit more lenient on hard working educated professionals. Seems like the wrong type of people to keep out.

Comment: This response should be deleted.